# why does this code produce a runtime error?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node *next;
};

void createlist(struct node **head)
{
    struct node *p,*temp;
    int n;
    printf("enter the number\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    p=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->a=n;
    if(*head==0) {
        *head=p;
        p->next=0;
        temp=p;
    }
    else {
        temp->next=p;
        temp=p;
        p->next=0;
    }
}

void frontbacksplit(struct node **head,struct node **head1,struct node **head2)
{
    int counter=0,i;
    struct node *temp,*p;
    temp=*head;
    while(temp!=0) {
        counter++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }   
    int n;
    if(counter%2==0) {
        n=counter/2;
    } else {
        n=(counter+1)/2;
    }
    temp=*head;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++) {
        if(*head1==0) {
            *head1=temp;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    p=temp;
    temp=temp->next;
    p->next=0;
    for(i=n+1;i<counter;i++) {
        if(*head2==0) {
            *head2=temp;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

void display(struct node **head)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=*head;
    while(temp!=0) {
        printf("%d\t",temp->a);
        temp=temp->next;
    }   
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int n=1,i,k;
    struct node *head3,*head1,*head2;
    head3=0;
    head1=0;
    head2=0;
    while(n==1) {
        printf("enter \n1-To add the elements\n2-To split the list into front and        the back\n3-To display the elements\n");
        scanf("%d",&i);
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
                createlist(&head3);
                break;
            case 2:
                frontbacksplit(&head3,&head1,&head2);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("enter\n1-To display front list\n2-To display rear list\n");
                scanf("%d",&k);
                switch(k)
                {
                    case 1:
                        display(&head1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        display(&head2);
                }
                break;
                default:
                printf("please enter a valid option\n");
        }
        printf("enter\n1-To continue\nany other number to exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I have written this code for front / back splitting of the linked list. For example if the list is [1 2 3 4 5] then this program splits the list into the two lists: front part (1 2 3) and back part(4 5), if the number of elements are equal both the parts get equal number of elements.

**Problem:** When I try to add elements in the source list, the first elements get added as usual but when I try add other element my program shows a run time error. I think there is problem with the pointer variable temp but almost same code for the creation of linked list worked properly.

I am using dev c++ ide on windows 8.

Of course point out if you did't like the way this question is asked, as this is my first time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use a decent title to your question such that people see at a first look what this is about. Generally you could profit from a look into the help text of this site to first learn how to ask questions, here.

Comment: I suppose you are hitting seg faults

Comment: i think error because of pointer leakage but can not identify the proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

On first look this line `temp->next = p` in `createlist` function is wrong, `temp` is a local variable, although you make it point to the element when the list is created for the first time the value is lost after the `createlist` function returns, so will you be accessing junk addresses in consecutive calls to `createlist`

Comment: but i compiled almost same type of code for creation of linked list with pointer temp and it worked correctly.

Comment: It compiles  because it is not a compilation error to access any address you wish, At runtime (doing ./your_exe) if you access illegal addresses the program is terminated by OS(typically) ... as @Nabarun suggests see the warning you compiler throws, before running the exectable

Comment: you mean that previous program ran accidentally.

Comment: I suppose previously you only created a list... did you print it??? I tried to compile your program and there is a warnings from the compiler like this:  `del.c:22:19: warning: ‘temp’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`  You add elements to list works because when you are only adding the elements you don't check if list is pointing to where it should: So here is my suggestion:  Add 2 elements to the list and try to print them, only then go ahead with split .....

Comment: On another note... I think you should read a book on C ... because clearly you lack the understanding of pointers ... I recommend K&R C

Comment: for this program i am not even able to create the list having nodes more than one.earlier i was talking about different program of the same type which worked correctly give me your email id i will send it to you.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer variable 'temp' in createlist() function is being used without assignment on calls subsequent to the first call. You could benefit using -Wall options if you are using GCC.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should change  to this:

```
void createlist(struct node **head)
{
    struct node *p,*temp;
    int n;
    printf("enter the number\n");
    while(scanf("%d",&n) != EOF)
    {
        p=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        p->a=n;
        if(*head==0)
        {
            *head=p;
            p->next=0;
            temp=p;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next=p;
            temp=p;
            p->next=0;
        }
    }
}
```